# Editing a particular element in inactive/hover/active states

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I am using the Foundation framework for my website and the following code is what I'm focusing on in my HTML file:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <li class="name">
            <h1><a href="#">jDispatch</a></h1>
        </li>
        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
            <a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="right">
            <li class="has-dropdown">
                <a href="#">Menu</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li><a href="#">Link one</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link two</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```

I am wondering how do I edit the dropdown button itself (which has text 'Menu') and edit it for all of its possible states (inactive, hovered over, and clicked on)?

By inspection of the code on Foundation's actual website (which of course uses their own framework), I have been able to modify the inactive and hovered over states with the following CSS code respectively:

```
/* inactive/not hovered or clicked */
.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {
    background: yellow;
    color: blue;
}

/* hovered over */
.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover {
    background: green;
    color: yellow;
}
```

I figured `.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):active {...}` would do the trick, but it didn't.

**EDIT**: Also how do I change the `font-family` of the dropdown items? Using `.top-bar-section ul li > a {...}` I can change the text color of the 'Menu' button and all of its dropdown items with `color`, but using `font-family` only changes the font for the 'Menu' button.

Comment: Duuuuude. Add a class.

Comment: Why the `not` segment? I don't see that class in your menu anyway.

Comment: Class? In what context? HTML? CSS? JavaScript? jQuery? Foundation?

Comment: Regarding the `not`, like I said, that's how the Foundation's website was styled, I just used "inspect element" in my browser and noticed that style was linked to that element and tried it on my code, and it worked.

Comment: That's not a great way to go about programming. You have a bunch of stuff in there that may not be necessary. For example, `:not(.has-form)` and `:not(.button)` don't seem to have a function.

Comment: Ok good I was wondering why it was there too haha, but how would you simplify it then? I thought `.top-bar-section ul li:hover > a` or `.top-bar-section ul li > a:hover` would do the trick, but neither are working.

Answer (score 0):

`.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):active {...}` will change the style for 'Menu' when clicked on.

But if 'Menu' is also linking to another page, you will only see the styles on active for a second, if you see them at all before the new page loads.

[Check out the codepen demo here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dojGKB)

```
.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):active {
   background-color: blue;
   color: white;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, how would I then adjust the button's style when the dropdown is active and I'm hovering over it's components (if you do that in your codepen demo you'll see it remains black when you hover over 'Link one')?

Comment: The problem is that the dropdown list is positioned absolutely, meaning you're no longer hovering over the parent menu item when you're over it. It's being handled by JavaScript.

Comment: When you say "hovering over parent menu...when you're over it.", what do you specifically mean by "it"? The parent menu button or one of the dropdown items? Is there still no way to style what I want with just CSS?

Comment: When you are hovering over the drop down elements, the 'Menu' header is not active. The best you can do with CSS is style the header for hover anywhere on the drop down menu, not only on drop down elements. Check out the code pen to see update.

Comment: I see, that would suffice for me then. Two follow up questions though: how come in your Codepen your menu drops down on hover, but when I run on my code on my local machine, I have to click to get items to drop down? Second question is in the edit of my OP.